# What is the significance of non-IDR IFrame?

Tags: mp4, h.264, video-processing, mpeg

For random access, I am under the impression that we need IDR (`nal_unit_type=5`), instead of non-IDR Iframe (`nal_unit_type=1`). 
Is this true? If so, what's point to have GOP start with a non-IDR Iframe, since a non-IDR Iframe is not enough to decode the remainder of a GOP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. An open GOP (starts with non IDR) is not independently decode-able anymore.
Typically the first couple B-frames reference frames from the previous GOP.
If your use case is playing the stream start to finish without seeking - than an open GOP with non-IDR is more efficient (fewer bits for the same quality).
If your application seeks a lot it gets more complicated. Typically you can either discard the B frames referencing the previous frame or start decoding two non IDRs backwards.
This doesn't solve the general case but works for most well behaved AVC streams.

Comment: Would you say the significance of non-IDR IFrame is to at least partially decode the GOP?

Comment: Yes. Let's assume your GOP in storage order  is: | non-IDR | B | B | P | ... | - you would have to discard the two B-frames since they likely reference something prior to the non-IDR but the rest should be decode-able. Keep in mind this is true for most AVC streams but not for all.

Comment: I marked this as answer unless something else comes up. nonIDR I-Frame can help generate thumbnails when seeking if that's considered important.